# Position <span> absolute over bottom of <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<textarea cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Note field is required." id="Note" name="Note" onkeyup="var element = document.getElementById('Note'); var counter = document.getElementById('Note_counter'); var characterCount = element.value.length;  var remaining = 1000 - parseInt(characterCount); if (remaining < 0) { element.value = element.value.substr(0, 1000); remaining = 0; } counter.innerHTML = remaining;" rows="2" style="width: 360px;"></textarea>
<span><span id="Note_counter">1000</span> characters remaining</span>
```

This comprises of a a `<textarea>` and a counter in a `<span>` element that follows. I wish to set the absolute positioning of the `<span>` element to be at the lower bottom part of the `<textarea>` regardless of where on the page the `<textarea>` is or how wide/narrow it is.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t41v0cyd/)

There could be multiple of these `<textarea/><span/>` combinations on the page. No jQuery can be used. I'm hoping I can do this with just css.

---

Edit:

I create all the html elements above with a custom html helper in ASP.NET MVC:

```
@CustomHtml.CustomTextAreaFor(Html, model => model.Note)
```

Comment: Can I wrap both of them by a `div`.

Comment: @alirezasafian - Yes. I create all the elements using a custom html helper with MVC, so I can include a parent div in the definition of this helper method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to wrap the textarea in a div and apply bottom padding and position relative to that.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <span class="char-count">1000</span>
</div>

.wrapper{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

.char-count{
  position:absolute;
  height:20px;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

You can style the span to look like the bottom of your textarea, that way the text will never visually overflow the character count.

Comment: Now, it might be the answer.

Comment: Sorry, pressed reply by mistake before adding the code :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to wrap your textarea and label in a div, apply position relative and set the div to inline-block. Then you will be able to position the label as you need it relative to the text-area.

HTML:

```
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
<textarea cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Note field is required." id="Note" name="Note" onkeyup="var element = document.getElementById('Note'); var counter = document.getElementById('Note_counter'); var characterCount = element.value.length;  var remaining = 1000 - parseInt(characterCount); if (remaining < 0) { element.value = element.value.substr(0, 1000); remaining = 0; } counter.innerHTML = remaining;" rows="2" style="width: 360px;"></textarea>
<span id="Note_counter_label"><span id="Note_counter">1000</span> characters remaining</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textarea-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmphakah/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As said before use a div to wrap both textarea and span. Your `texarea` has an `css height`, so put the `div` to `position:relative`, the add top of the `span` equal to the textarea height `(top:100px)`. Elements with absolute position are positioned compared to their parent if that one has `position:relative`