# Looking for a way to put a paste button in placeholder of textarea? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, button, textarea, placeholder

I am making a word count application in javascript. I just wanna put a paste button in the placeholder of the textarea so that user doesn't need to use ctrl + paste to paste the string. Is there someway that i could do it?
[Picture of the placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfM0p.png)

I just wanna do something like this in the photo above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position <span> absolute over bottom of <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775363/position-span-absolute-over-bottom-of-textarea)

Comment: I don't think that is relevant this one is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633947/4308987 async function paste(input) {
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  input.value = text;
}

Comment: Thank you for helping. I just updated my question. This doesn't answer my question . I just wanna do something in the photo I put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it right, but say the user copied something, you want it to be automatically pasted into the textarea?
If so, you should use the focus event.
That way, by binding it to the focus event, you are sure that the user mostly isn't going to focus/select the textarea unless they have the string copied.

Comment: I just wanna make a button in the placeholder and when the user click the button, it will paste the text from the user's clipboard.

Comment: I think the first comment by Sven is helpful in your case, because it allows you to create a button outside of the textarea and then move it inside using CSS, I've done it before.

But in any case, here's a simple proof of concept to achieve it without a button, using Solomon's function and a simple onclick event (if that's of any help):
`<html><head></head><body>
<textarea onclick='paste(this)'></textarea>
</body>
<script>
    async function paste(input) 
    { const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
     input.value = text; } 
</script>
</html>`